# Laravel Eloquent ORM find related object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

What is the correct way to find a related object based on a `where` clause with Eloquent ORM?

For example, I want to find a specific Product object that is related to a Store object.  I thought I could do something like this:

```
$store = Store::where('hash', Input::get('s'))->first();
$product = $store->products->where('ext_id', 2)->get();
```

However, I'm getting an error that `where` is an unknown method. If instead of where I use `find`, that works correctly:

```
$product = $store->products->find(1);
```

Why can't I use `where` this way?

Comment: You cant use the where on this occasion but if you do $store->products()->where('ext_id', 2)->get() , that should work. The () allow you to query again. The reason for this is because $store->products is a collection.

Comment: But does this run an additional query? So $store->products() runs a query to select all products related to the store, and then ->get() runs a query again to select all products related to the store where ext_id = 2? It seems like the first query is completely unnecessary isn't it?

Comment: Yes, based on the output of DB::getQueryLog(), it looks like it's running 2 queries. The first one seems irrelevant. There must be a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: To get rid of this could you just eager load the relation with Store::with('products')->where('hash', Input::get('s'))->first(); and then use $store->products()->where('ext_id', 2)->get()? Im not too sure on the output but that could reduce the query to 1.

Comment: Even then $store->products() still runs another query.  It doesn't seem to matter that it was previously eager loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$product = $store
    ->products()
    ->where('ext_id', 2)->get();
```

This will **not** run 2 queries.

The difference is this:

```
$store->products() // relation object you can query
$store->products // already fetched related collection / model (depending on relation type)
```

Also you can use eager loading:

```
$store =  Store::where('hash', Input::get('s'))
    ->with(['products' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('ext_id', 2);
    }])->first();
```

This will load only `ext_id = 2` products on the store, that will be accessible via `$store->products`

---

Now, there are different methods `find` involved:

```
$store->products()->find(1); // runs select ... where id=1
$store->products->find(1); // gets model with id 1 from the collection
```